# Visual Studio Tools for Office Edit multiple files

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am using VSTO to hopefully replace `xxx` to `yyy` across several Excel files in a directory. I succeeded to do that in the current sheet by doing

```
Worksheet currentSheet = Globals.ThisaddIn.GetActiveWorksheet();
```

What should I do to use VSTO to grab all the Excel fils in the directory at a time to avoid to click the add-on from each current sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code Runs through all the Excel on a directory, run some code, save and close the Excel instance.
the _path is the Path to the directory where the Workbooks live.

```
private void runFiles(string _path) 
    {
        string path = _path;

        var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        FileInfo [] listOfFiles = d.GetFiles("*.xlsx*").ToArray();

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        foreach (FileInfo file in listOfFiles)
        {

                var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file.FullName);
                Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets["SheetName"];
                //Code Here;


                xlWorkBook.Save();
                xlWorkBook.Close();
        }

        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
```

Comment: Works in perfection, you rock

Comment: Glad i was of assistance :)